# Compare datatable to IList

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datatable, ilist

I have a `DataTable`, called `dt`, that has two columns and is populated by reading data from a CSV file. The 2 columns are `Keys` and their respective `Descriptions` approximately 7000 rows.

Now I have `IList<string>` keys, which is nothing but keys (same keys as in the `DataTable`).

How do I match the `IList<string>` keys to the `DataTable` and retrieve a final output as a `new DataTable` that has only the rows matching with the `IList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r => list.Contains(r.Field<int>("id")))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

You can also create a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that in your query.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
//.... ids in the list

HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list);
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r => hashSet.Contains(r.Field<int>("id")))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Entity framework:

> class DbItem
>           {
>               public int Key { get; set; }
>               public int Value { get; set; }
>           }

```
var keysInMemory = new List<int>(); // put your Keys here
var values = new StringBuilder();
values.AppendFormat("{0}", keysInMemory[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < keysInMemory.Count; i++)
            values.AppendFormat(", {0}", keysInMemory[i]);

var sql = string.Format(@"SELECT dt.Key Key, dt.Value Value FROM [dbo].[dt] where Key  IN ({0})", values.ToString());

var result = await _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DbItem>(sql).ToListAsync();
```

Note that "Contains" with IQueryable has REALLY BAD performance